# How can I edit the sound effects?

Tags: worms-reloaded

I would like to know if I can edit the SFX of the taunts of worms.

For example: "Something I said"

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the game's sound bank. 
I found [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d9-QcIcew7Y) and the process is explained in the description and in the first comments.
Also you can watch the video to see the final results.

Your custom soundbank (`.wav` files) will have to be in this path :

```
C:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\common\worms reloaded\Audio\Default\Win\CustomBanks\
```

Also here's the name of the sound files to create you file.

```
Fire Punch
First Blood
Flawless
Go Away
Grenade
Hello
Hurry
Incoming
I'll get you
Jump 1
Jump 2
Just You Wait
Kamikaze
Laugh
Leave me alone
Missed
Noooooo
Oh Dear
Oi Nutter
Oof 1
Oof 2
Oof 3
Oops
Orders
Ouch
Ow 1
Ow 2
Ow 3
Perfect
Revenge
Run Away
Stupid
Take Cover
Traitor
Uh Oh
Victory
Watch This
What the
Yes Sir
You'll Regret that
```

Comment: As for the location, I tried to place the .xom file, But without success.
I check in customize> Manage team> and the speech I added was not was not there.
As for the editing, I did not understand exactly what I need to do to change them individually.

Comment: Just make them in the sound bank editor under customize in the main menu

Comment: This is what I see http://i.imgur.com/Nhh8w.jpg
Is this possibility should be somewhere else?